# How to configure apt-get in ubuntu 11.10 behind proxy?

Tags: apt

I want to configure apt-get in my ubuntu 11.10 version by editing apt.conf file but not getting positive result.pls reply if anybody can...

Comment: Share what you actually changed in the configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Placing a line like

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy-address:8000/";
```

in a new file in for example `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10-proxy` should do the trick. Be sure to have set up HTTP mirrors in your `sources.list` if you want to connect to an HTTP proxy or just add another `Acquire::ftp::Proxy` line for FTP mirror/proxy. Also change address and port number accordingly.